# onListItemClick not working properly if images are loaded

Tags: android, android-listview

I had a custom listview with two textviews and an image view. On clicking of each row iam showing an custom dialog. After opening the listview and click on the row iam able to view the dialog whereas if i scroll and click on the row dialog is not displayed.

My onListItemclick code is as follows
`

```
final Dialog password = new Dialog(VCStegoInboxWithOutCheckboxes.this);
        password.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        password.setTitle("Enter your Password");

        final EditText getPassword = (EditText) password
                .findViewById(R.id.edconfirmpwd);
        Button okButton = (Button) password.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String ConfirmCode = getPassword.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getSharedPreferences(
                        "UserName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String Password = settingsActivity.getString("Password", null);

                if (ConfirmCode.equals(Password)) {
                                        Intent showMsgIntent = new Intent();
                        showMsgIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),
                                VCStegoShowMessageScreen.class);

                        startActivity(showMsgIntent);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "InvalidPassword",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                password.dismiss();

            }
        });
        Button cancelButton = (Button) password.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Entered on cancel button clicked");
                password.dismiss();

            }
        });
        password.show();

    }
```

Another thing i observed is if it is a textview (instead of imageview) even though if i scroll iam able to display dialog for each and every row.

My adapter method is

```
public class InboxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private TextView Tvname, TVtimeStamp;
    private ImageView IVmsg;

    public InboxAdapter(Context context, List<VCStegoInboxList> inboxList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        VCStegoInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist = inboxList;
    }
    public class ViewHolder{
           private TextView Tvname;
           private TextView TVtimeStamp;              
           private ImageView IVmsg;
          }

    public int getCount() {
        return VCStegoInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.size();
    }

    // @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return VCStegoInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.get(position);
    }

    // @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

           if (convertView==null){

            holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inboxtextviews, null);
        Tvname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvinboxname);

        IVmsg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvinboxmsg);



        TVtimeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtimeStamp);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
       }else{

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }
           Tvname.setText(VCStegoInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist
                .get(position).getname());
           IVmsg.setImageBitmap(VCStegoInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.get(
                    position).getBitmap());
           TVtimeStamp.setText(VCStegoInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.get(
                    position).getTimeStamp());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

My xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvinboxname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tvinboxmsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvinboxname"

    android:contentDescription="@string/contentDes" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtimeStamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvinboxmsg"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: You need to post all of your list code as it seems the problem is with your list and not your dialog.

Comment: where is your listitem click?

Comment: Adapter method and xml are posted. Actually if i replace the image view with list item then iam not getting any problem.And the list with image view is displayed correctly. only after  scrolling iam not able to get the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign id for your root layout id like

```
  <RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<your TextView/>
<your ImageView/>
<your TextView/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

get the root in adapter class like

```
root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
```

write the onclick listener above `return convertView;` line you adapter class
onclick listener is like this

```
root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//toast display dialog code here
}
});
```